# Unable to install program in self extracting cabinet using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to set up a test SharePoint server for trusted (AD FS) authentication on a stamped test environment that consists of a SharePoint server (server 2016) and a domain controller (server 2008R2).  I'm writing the script to run on the SharePoint server and use a remote session to configure the DC because the DC only has PowerShell 2.0 which is missing some convenient functionality.

I have a specific segment of the script that runs a script block on the DC which downloads the AD FS 2.0 installer, a self extracting cabinet, and tries to install it.  Every line of the block executes except for the actual installation.  If I log onto the machine and run those same lines it works perfectly.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $domainControllerSession -ScriptBlock {
    $installerUrl = "https://download.microsoft.com/download/F/3/D/F3D66A7E-C974-4A60-B7A5-382A61EB7BC6/RTW/W2K8R2/amd64/AdfsSetup.exe"
    $filename = "$($PWD.Path)\AdfsSetup.exe"
    $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $wc.DownloadFile($installerUrl, $filename)
    Start-Process -FilePath $filename -ArgumentList "/quiet" -Wait
}
```

I tried manually extracting the contents (using /x:) and then executing the setup file but there was no change in result (Note: The files are extracted but the extractor process never exits, this doesn't seem pertinent to the problem).  I also moved to the DC and created a session to localhost and got the same exact behavior.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName Localhost
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
>> $filename = "$($PWD.Path)\AdfsSetup.exe"
>> write-host $filename
>> Test-Path -Path $filename
>> Start-Process -FilePath $filename -ArgumentList "/quiet" -Wait
>> Test-Path -Path 'C:\Program Files\Active Directory Federation Services 2.0'
>> }
>>
C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\AdfsSetup.exe
True
False
PS C:\Users\Administrator>
```

## Update 1

I ran the process with the `/Logfile` parameter and confirmed that the installation is failing due to an access denied error. I've also confirmed that, as expected, the remote session is running under the same administrator account that I am using to initiate the session.  I am assuming that the missing ingredient here is that the remote session is not running in an elevated shell. However, I can't seem to get that working either.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
  Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "& C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\AdfsSetup.exe /quiet /Logfile C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\AdfsSetup.log" -Wait -PassThru
}
```

The error is the same.

Comment: Active the log file to see what's happening there `AdfsSetup.exe /LogFile C:\AdfsSetup.log`.

Comment: I should have looked for how to log ...

`The installation of "Windows Identity Foundation (WIF)" failed. Error: Access is denied`